# How to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A>B)$ using the Jeffrey Prior

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

Let say that you created 2 marketing campaigns. You sent 200 impressions on these campaigns as follow:

- Campaign A : Got 100 impressions and 2 successes with a value of 1.5$ per success
- Campaign B : Got 100 impressions and 1 success with a value of 2$ per success

Using the Jeffrey prior 0.5,0.5 how do you calculate $\mathbb{P}(A > B)$ or $\mathbb{P}(A < B)$?

Here is a online calculator : https://win-vector.shinyapps.io/CampaignPlanner/ > Choose task "Evaluate Campaign". For the given problem the result is $\mathbb{P}(A > B)$ = 0.6144371 = 61%

How to get this number?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bayesian statistics -- is the Jeffrey prior a commonly used prior distribution? If not, or maybe even if so, your question might be more readily answered if you add a link describing the Jeffrey prior.

Comment: @William: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior (with an s).  For a proportion, it is $\sim \text{Beta}(\frac12,\frac12)$, while a uniform prior would be $\sim \text{Beta}(1,1)$